# Leaflet problem with filtering the geoJSON layers

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to make geoJSON properties selectable in the dropdown list.

The example comes from here:
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

Combining with my code it looks as follows:

```
   <select class="selection">
                                <option id="vm2" name="verify" value="total">All</option>
                                <option id="completed2" name="verify" value="completed">Completed</option>
                            </select>
```

JS

```
  var url = 'json/vm2.json';  // Here is the url path to my GeoJSON file, 


     function getColor(Type){   //layer 2 Virgin Media
     return Type == 'Infill' ? 'yellow' :
      Type == 'MDU' ? 'orange' :
                        'orange';
       }    
    function style(feature) {
    if (feature.properties.Type === "MDU" && 
    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
    return{
    fillColor: '#d4a270',
    fillOpacity: '#d4a270',
     weight: 0.5
    }
    if (feature.properties.Type === "Infill" && 
    feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")   
    return{
    fillColor: '#efefa9',
    fillOpacity: '#efefa9',
    weight: 0.5
    }
    else
   return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
    fillOpacity: 1,
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.75,
   //color: '#ffffff',
   //dashArray: '3'
   };
  }


   var infill; 
   var mdu;    

  $.when(
      $.getJSON(url),
      ).done (function(data) {

      infill = L.geoJson(data, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Type == "Infill" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);  //Note turned on to start map with Data, Checkbox has checked property.

   mdu = L.geoJson(data, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        radius:6,
        opacity: .5,
        //color: "#000",
        color:getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
        fillOpacity: 0.8

        }).bindTooltip(feature.properties.Owner);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
            return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
        }
        }).addTo(map);
});

  // Handles the check boxes being turned on/off
   document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").addEventListener('change', 
  function() {
        if(this.checked) map.addLayer(infill)
          else map.removeLayer(infill)
            if (clickmark != undefined) {  //i.e. if it exists...
            //function all to remove the yellow select circle, could call function to clear table from here.
                map.removeLayer(clickmark);
            };
        })

    document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").addEventListener('change', 
    function() {
        if(this.checked) map.addLayer(mdu)
          else map.removeLayer(mdu)
            if (clickmark != undefined) {
                map.removeLayer(clickmark);
            };
        })
```

//2nd Layer in map

```
// click marker
   var clickmark;

 // When you click on a circle, it calls the onMapClick function and passes the layers coordinates.
 // I grab the coords which are X,Y, and I need to flip them to latLng for a marker,  
  function onMapClick(coords) {
    //console.log(coords);
    var thecoords = coords.toString().split(',');
    var lat = thecoords[1];
    var lng = thecoords[0];
    //if prior marker exists, remove it.
    if (clickmark != undefined) {
      map.removeLayer(clickmark);
    };

     clickmark = L.circleMarker([lat,lng],{
        radius: 8,
        color: "yellow",
        fillColor:  "yellow",
        fillOpacity: 0.8}
     ).addTo(map);
}
```

//filtered layers

```
   //Initial Setup  with layer Verified No
     mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color:'black',
            fillColor:  'red',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 8
        })
       },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Status);
      },
      filter: function(feature, layer) {   
         return (feature.properties.Status === "Completed_and_invoiced" );
    },

    });     

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   mdu.addData(data);
});

 /// END Initial Setup

   //Using a Layer Group to add/ remove data from the map.
   var myData =  L.layerGroup([]);
    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map); 


   //If Radio Button one is clicked.  
   document.getElementById("radioOne").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status === "Completed_and_invoiced" ';
   console.log(theExpression);  

    myData.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(myData);

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'red',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Status);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return (feature.properties.Status === "Completed_and_invoiced" );
        },

    });


    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);;
});
```

Where I considered one layer so far.

My geoJSON snippet looks as follows:

```
   {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Owner": 181616,
    "Type": "Infill",
    "Status": "Completed_and_invoiced",
    "Ticket_ID": "VM/TIK/804768",
    "NBU": 181616,
    "Address": "Morien Crescent & Dyfryn Road Pontypridd",
    "Postcode": "CF37 5PT",
    "Date_issued_from_VM": "",
    "Asbestos_rep": "N/A",
    "Planner": "Richard Dean",
    "Surveyor": "Richard Dean",
    "STATS_Applied_for_date": "N/A",
    "STATS_compleeted": "N/A",
    "ACTUAL_Internal_QC_Date": "",
    "VM_ECD_date": "",
    "Client_Home_Count": 239,
    "Post_Survey_Home_Count": 254,
    "General_notes": "Emailed water on 9.5. AJ to chase on 13.05",
    "Directory": "file://Z:\\\\Fixed Line\\\\Design & Build\\\\2. Clients\\\\Virgin Media\\\\1. 
   Small Infill Projects\\\\2. NBUs\\\\NBU 181616",
    "Sharepoint": ""
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -3.31934,
      51.59221
    ]
   }
```

In the result I am getting sth like 2 the same layers overlapped with no filteration at all.

[image]

Could anybody advise what to do?

UPDATE:

Following step by step this example:

var mdu;

//Initial Setup  with layer Verified No
    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

```
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color:'black',
            fillColor:  'red',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 8
        })
    },  
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Type);
    },
    filter: function(feature, layer) {   
         return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
    },

});     

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   mdu.addData(data);
});
```

/// END Initial Setup

```
//Using a Layer Group to add/ remove data from the map.
var myData =  L.layerGroup([]);
    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map); 


      //If Radio Button one is clicked.  
document.getElementById("radioOne").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
theExpression = 'feature.properties.Type == "MDU"';
console.log(theExpression); 

    myData.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(myData);

    mdu = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'red',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Status);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ) && (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced");
        },

    });


    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);;
});



    //If Radio button two is clicked.
document.getElementById("radioTwo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
theExpression = '(feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ) && (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced")';   
console.log(theExpression);
    map.removeLayer(myData);
    myData.clearLayers();

    ci_data = L.geoJson(null, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color:'black',
                fillColor:  'green',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 8
            })
        },  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Status);
        },
        filter: function(feature, layer) {   
             return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ) && (feature.properties.Status == "Completed_and_invoiced");
        },

    });

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           mdu.addData(data);
    });

    myData.addLayer(mdu);
    myData.addTo(map);
});
```

Only 1st layer seems to work (red), but green is still inactive

[image]

My HTML form

```
    <form>
     <input type="radio" id="radioOne" name="verify" value="MDU" checked> All &nbsp;<div class="box red" ></div> <br>
     <input type="radio" id="radioTwo" name="verify" value="Completed_and_invoiced" > Completed &nbsp;<div class="box green" ></div> 
     <br>
     </form><hr>
```

Comment: maybe you can create a https://jsfiddle.net/ , you have posted a lot of code and that makes it better to read

Comment: It looks more or less like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krukarius/abnkfxcL/

The demo map is here:
https://mariusz-krukar.mkrgeo.pl/en/workshop/media/MDU_demo.html

Comment: sorry but i don't understand your code ... But maybe i can help you so. You can try to add the gejson data to a featuregroup and every time you change your selectbox call `featuregroup.clearLayers()` then all markers are away. Then you call the function from the beginning to load the markers new, but filtered. This is not the way with the best performance but it is a start

Comment: I will check it out later and let U know, hopefully good news